# I AM A MAN, NOT A MACHINE

Tags: support, user-interface

So, I just posted a long meta answer. It was the first interaction I've had with an SE website (other than loading pages), in about 9 hours. I was already logged in via cookie. I have over 45,000 reputation here on Arqade, and another ~7500 rep scattered around the rest of the network. I am about as trusted a user as a user without a diamond gets to be.

And yet, when posting that answer, which, I'll reiterate, was not a rapid fire action of any sort, I was confronted with a Captcha. This [Status Completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143455/i-am-not-a-robot/) MSO question indicates that users with over 10k rep should almost never see such a thing.

Why do you hate me Arqade? What did I ever do to lose your trust?

Comment: IT'S AN OUTRAGE!

Comment: I'm guessing, much like Google search CAPTCHAs, that someone else sharing your network was bogging down a SE site. That or a browser addon/program on your computer was bogging down SE.

Comment: [This](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/8079/6066)?  May be useful for analysis.

Comment: any chance you have javascript turned off?  the captcha is always there when js is off

Comment: @Resorath Home connection from an ordinary residential ISP. Nobody else is using it to connect to an SE site. Matt, yes, that's the answer. Spartacus: No, JS is definitely on.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I regularly encounter CAPTCHAS and and even end up getting myself IP-blocked on MSO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you did there, but somehow you managed to hit the answer submission route twice within a few seconds. So the spam-checker got spooked and decided to test you.

## Congratulations, you're probably human!

...for now...

Comment: But what if he's a cylon?!